# В чем разница методов фрагмента onCreateView и onViewCreated?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Хотелось бы понять главные отличия. И в каких случаях использовать тот или другой?

Comment: Судя по названию, первое вызывается до создания View, а второе после

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`OnCreateView` вызывается в момент создания `View` и в нём инится сам `layout`

`OnViewCreated` вызывается после того как `layout` проинициализирован.

Что и когда использовать?
`OnCreateView` - тут только создаем `layout`

`OnViewCreated` - тут уже привязываем логику к вьюхам. Это гарантирует что вьюха создана, и никакие `null pointer`'ы падать не будут.

На самом деле можно обходиться без `OnViewCreated`, и всё делать в `OnCreateView`

Так что тут число логика разделения обязаностей для методов.

Реалиная ситуация, когда я использую `OnViewCreated` - я использую `Butterknife` и в базовом фрагменте я реализовал `OnCreateView` где вызываю `Butternife.bind(this,view)`
А вся логика наследников уже в `OnViewCreated`. А так пришлось бы каждый раз вызывать `OnCreateView.super()` и в случае множественного наследования могут быть коллизии и всё в таком роде