# Чем отличается onCreateView от onViewCreated во фрагменте?

Tags: java, android

Чем отличается метод `onCreateView()` от метода `onViewCreated()` во фрагменте? И в каком методе нужно работать с БД или парсингом JSON?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/740935/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-oncreateview-%D0%B8-onviewcreated

Comment: Все понятно стало. Значит в onViewCreated всю логику можно делать. Спасибо